# Pattern matching record types

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching

Let's consider the following `Point` record type:

```
type Point = { x:int; y:int }
```

I'd like to make a predicate that tells me whether a given Point is in a valid region.

```
let insideBounds p =
  let notInside c = c < 0 || c > 100
  match p with
  | {x=i; y=_} when notInside i -> false
  | {x=_; y=j} when notInside j -> false
  | _                           -> true
```

This works, yet I wonder if there's an  alternative way of achieving the same result having as insideBounds signature

```
let insideBounds {x=i; y=j}
```

instead, still making use of pattern matching?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define an *active pattern* that tests whether a value is inside a range specified as an argument:

```
let (|InRange|_|) (min, max) v = 
  if v >= min && v <= max then Some () else None
```

Then you can define `insideBounds` like this:

```
let insideBounds = function
  | { x = InRange (0, 100); y = InRange (0, 100) } -> true
  | _ -> false
```

The first case matches when both `x` anad `y` members are in the specified range. The active pattern returns `option unit`, which means that it doesn't bind any values. The `(0, 100)` is an input argument and the pattern matches when the value (`x` or `y`) is in the range.

(In other context `match 10 with InRange (0

Comment: Which can then be handily rewritten in function-esque style: `let insideBounds {x=i; y=j} = 
  let inRange = ((|InRange|_|) (0, 100) >> Option.isSome);
  inRange i && inRange j` :-)

Comment: @Tomas That's cool.  The pattern matching statement is acting like a Maybe pattern.

Answer (score 4):

Sure.

```
type Point = { x:int; y:int }

let insideBounds {x=i; y=j} =
  let notInside c = c < 0 || c > 100
  not (notInside i || notInside j)
```

I'd recommend inverting your logic to make it clearer:

```
let insideBounds {x=i; y=j} =
  let isInside c = c >= 0 && c <= 100
  isInside i && isInside j
```

As a general rule, it's better for boolean functions/properties, etc to be affirmative. That way, negation retains it's negativity, so to speak.

Comment: I am sorry I wasn't clear enough. Your solution is way better than what I've shown above (I was actually using *exactly* the same solution as you've shown in my own code). I was only trying to understand how to accomplish the pattern matching with that function signature.

Comment: The important bit is that pattern matching occurs in many places, including function arguments. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx (see Remarks)